# Can I configure apache/mod_wsgi so that the Alias URL path is not stripped before it reaches my Django app?

Tags: apache-2.2, django, mod-wsgi

I am trying to configure Apache to host a Django webservice and a PHP website.

All URLs with the pattern `www.mysite.com/api` should be directed to the Django service.
All other URLs (e.g. `www.mysite.com`) should be directed to the PHP website.

My virtual host config looks like this:

```
...
WSGIScriptAlias /api /var/www/mysite.com/apache/django.wsgi
<Directory /var/www/mysite.com/apache>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

Alias / /var/www/mysite.com/apache/php/
<Directory /var/www/mysite.com/apache/php>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
...
```

This directs each request to the correct handler.  However,  my Django **urls.py** looks like this:

```
...
api_patterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^api/1.0/$', views.api_root),
    url(r'^api/1.0/oauth/', 
        include('oauth2_provider.urls', 
                namespace='oauth2_provider')),
...
```

This fails to match any URLs because it is expecting them to begin with `api`.  This prefix is, of course, being stripped off before it gets here (when the requests arrive here they are in the format `1.0/oauth` etc.).

Is there any way to pass a fully intact URL through to Django?

### Solution

Graham Dumpleton, the author of mod_wsgi, suggested a couple of approaches to fix this, both of which worked (see the accepted answer below).

I went for the solution he suggests in UPDATE 1.  Appending `/api` to the file path solves the problem:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /api /var/www/mysite.com/apache/django.wsgi/api
```

i.e. `/api` is no longer stripped off the URL by the time it reaches Django.

So here are the relevant parts of my working config:

```
...
DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.com/apache/php

WSGIScriptAlias /api /var/www/mysite.com/apache/service/django.wsgi/api
<Directory /var/www/mysite.com/apache/service>
    WSGIProcessGroup www.mysite.com
    WSGIPassAuthorization On
    Options -Indexes
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

# PHP web site
<Directory /var/www/mysite.com/apache/php>
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
    DirectoryIndex index.php
</Directory>
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are seeing is exactly how it is generally meant to work. A WSGI application should not care nor embed knowledge about where it is being mounted. In other words, you should not have 'api' as a prefix in urls.py. Why do you believe you need 'api' prefix in urls.py?

---

UPDATE 1

You may be able to use:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /api /var/www/mysite.com/apache/django.wsgi/api
```

I can't remember the exact formula right now and whether that is correct, but try it.

Comment: Well, my Django app is not called `api`.  I would like to use the same URL patterns in the dev server and Apache.

Comment: I guess neither of those are particularly good reasons...

Comment: That is a deficiency of the development server, although other pure Python WSGI servers tend not to be any better. See possible workaround as update to answer.

Comment: Your workaround worked - thanks very much!  I had to modify my approach slightly - I have added it as an edit to the original question.  Thanks again!

Comment: You should not have been using Alias with '/' to start with. Use DocumentRoot instead.

Comment: I've updated the solution in my question.  Thanks very much for your (extra) help!